# Adding 2nd search to regex pattern?

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, regex

```
// LINE 1   
<td align="left" nowrap><font face="courier, monospace" size="-1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(2002&nbsp;GC1)</font></td>

// LINE 2
<td align="left" nowrap><font face="courier, monospace" size="-1">&nbsp;99942&nbsp;Cocoon</font></td>
```

I have created a simple regular expression to scrape a little data I need from the HTML lines above, the expression works well and puts the data I need in two groups.

Regular Expression Pattern = `([0-9]+)&nbsp;([A-Za-z0-9]+)`

- LINE1: Group1 = 2002,  Group2 = GC1
- LINE2: Group1 = 99942, Group2 = Cocoon

Having run this through my data I have now noticed that there is a new type of HTML line that has an extra number at the start that I should get.

```
// LINE 3
<td align="left" nowrap><font face="courier, monospace" size="-1">162421&nbsp;(2000&nbsp;CG70)</font></td>
```

- LINE3: Group1 = 2000, Group2 = CG70

What I am trying to do is alter my pattern to additionally capture `162421` this matches the same pattern  `([0-9]+)&nbsp;` but being new to regular expressions I am unsure how to add this possibility into my pattern. Each time I try I either negate my already working search or I overwrite part of the result.

NOTE: I am using this with: NSRegularExpression on iOS.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to add a capture group for early digits in the string. In the example, these digits are followed by "&nbsp"; (one or many times) and "(", and all of this is optional for the regex to match.

```
  (?:([0-9]+)(?:&nbsp;)+\()?([0-9]+)&nbsp;([A-Za-z0-9]+)
  // ^                      ^             ^                 capture groups
```

The trickiest part comes with capture ranges.

Now you have one capture group more, you will always have 4 ranges when querying the `NSTextCheckingResult` object (0-index range is the *entire* match range, others are capture ranges).

But some times, only the last two will be valid.
To be sure, test the `location` member of the `NSRange` against `NSNotFound`. If the test succeed then the range is valid and you match and capture early digits, otherwise not.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
([0-9]+)&nbsp;([A-Za-z0-9]*)
```

Btw. I use [this site](http://regexpal.com) to test regular expressions, very useful.